# How to apply checkValidity() in forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three column form with 1st column having input fields and next two having checkboxes,if i submit my form without entering anything then an alert appears for 2nd and 3rd column on page top and then alert msg appears for column1. How to use this method here?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-  scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Study Schedule</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js">        </script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">   </script>


    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="page-header">
    <div class="well">
    <h1 align="center" style="color:Brown;"><b>Study Schedule </b>   </h1>
    </div>
    </div>
    <form>

    <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

    <!--Column 1-->

    <div class="col-lg-3 jumbotron">
    <div class="form-group">
    <span><b>Teacher Name</b></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>
    <select class="form-control" required >
    <option value="">Select name</option>
    <option>Rachna</option>
    <option>Sanjay</option>
    <option>Seema</option>
    <option>Shivani</option>
    <option>Roop Singh</option>
    <option>Satnaam</option>
    <option>Rakesh</option>
    <option>Shalini</option>
    </select>  </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <span><b>Teacher Name</b></span>

    <select class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select name</option>
    <option>Rachna</option>
    <option>Sanjay</option>
    <option>Seema</option>
    <option>Shivani</option>
    <option>Roop Singh</option>
    <option>Satnaam</option>
    <option>Rakesh</option>
    <option>Shalini</option>
    </select> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <span><b>Teacher Name</b></span>

    <select class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select name</option>
    <option>Rachna</option>
    <option>Sanjay</option>
    <option>Seema</option>
    <option>Shivani</option>
    <option>Roop Singh</option>
    <option>Satnaam</option>
    <option>Rakesh</option>
    <option>Shalini</option>
    </select> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <span><b>Teacher Name</b></span>

    <select class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select name</option>
    <option>Rachna</option>
    <option>Sanjay</option>
    <option>Seema</option>
    <option>Shivani</option>
    <option>Roop Singh</option>
    <option>Satnaam</option>
    <option>Rakesh</option>
    <option>Shalini</option>
    </select> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <span><b>Teacher Name</b></span>

    <select class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select name</option>
    <option>Rachna</option>
    <option>Sanjay</option>
    <option>Seema</option>
    <option>Shivani</option>
    <option>Roop Singh</option>
    <option>Satnaam</option>
    <option>Rakesh</option>
    <option>Shalini</option>
    </select> 
    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-1">
    </div>
    <!--Column 2-->


    <div class="col-lg-3 jumbotron">

    <!--Row 1-->  
    <div class="row">
    <b>Subject</b>  
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>           
    <div class="input-group">
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input name="chk[]"   type="checkbox" value="" >S1</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >S2</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >S3</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >S4</label>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate()
    {
        var flag=0;
        var chks = document.getElementsByName('chk[]');
        var hasChecked = false;
        for(var i=0;i<chks.length;i++)
        {
            if(chks[i].checked)
            {
                hasChecked = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(hasChecked==false)
        {
            alert("Please select atleast one subject");
            return false;
        }
        if(flag==1)     
        {       
            var chks = document.getElementsByName('chk[]');
            var hasChecked = false;
            for(var i=0;i<chks.length;i++)
            {
                if(chks[i].checked)
                {
                    hasChecked = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(hasChecked==false)
            {
                alert("Please select atleast one Day");
                return false;
            }
                return true;
        }
    }
    </script>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!--Row 2-->
    <div class="row">
    <b>Subject</b>  
    <div class="input-group">
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" value=""   >S1</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" value=""  >S2</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" value="" >S3</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" value="" >S4</label>

    </div>
    </div>

    <!--Row 3-->
    <div class="row">
    <b>Subject</b>    
    <div class="input-group">
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" value="" >S1</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" value="" >S2</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" value="" >S3</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" value="" >S4</label>

    </div>
    </div>

    <!--Row 4-->
    <div class="row">
    <b>Subject</b>    
    <div class="input-group">
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" value="" >S1</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" value="" >S2</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" value="" >S3</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" value="" >S4</label>

    </div>
    </div>

    <!--Row 5-->
    <div class="row">
    <b> Subject</b>    
    <div class="input-group">
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" value="" >S1</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" value="" >S2</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" value="" >S3</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" value="" >S4</label>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>







    <div class="col-lg-1">  
    </div>
    <!--Column 3-->


    <div class="col-lg-4 jumbotron">

    <!--Row 1-->
    <div class="row">
            <b>Class Days</b> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>
             <div class="input-group">
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Mon</label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Tue</label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Wed</label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Thr</label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Fri</label>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function day()
    {
    var chks = document.getElementsByName('chk[]');
    var hasChecked = false;
    for(var i=0;i<chks.length;i++)
    {
        if(chks[i].checked)
        {
            hasChecked = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(hasChecked==false)
    {
        alert("Please select atleast one day");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    }
    </script>       

            </div>
     </div>

    <!--Row  2-->
    <div class="row">
            <b>Class Days</b>
             <div class="input-group">
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Mon</label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Tue</label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Wed</label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Thr</label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Fri</label>

            </div>
        </div>

    <!--Row 3-->
    <div class="row">
            <b>Class Days</b>
           <div class="input-group">
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Mon</label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Tue</label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Wed</label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Thr</label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Fri</label>

            </div>
        </div>

    <!--Row 4-->
    <div class="row">
            <b>Class Days</b>
            <div class="input-group">
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Mon</label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Tue</label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Wed</label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Thr</label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Fri</label>

            </div>
        </div>

    <!--Row 5-->
    <div class="row">
            <b> Class Days</b>
             <div class="input-group">
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Mon</label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Tue</label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Wed</label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Thr</label>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input name="chk[]" type="checkbox" value="" >Fri</label>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="col-lg-10">

    <b>Prinicipal Name</b>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" required>

    </div>
    <br>



    <div class="col-lg-4">

    <b>Date of schedule Application</b>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id="datetimepicker1">
                <input type='text' class="form-control" required/>
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker();
        });
    </script>
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-10" align="center">
    <div class="row">
    <div class ="btn btn-info" role="button">
    <input type="Submit"  class="btn btn-info" value="Submit"    onclick="validate();">
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>  


    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">     </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why are you using JS for a form instead of PHP?

Answer (score 0):

In  `validate()` function you used 2nd column as initial. Use first column and in submit button give return like this `onclick="return validate()"`